# How do I add query string to URL in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

What is the simplest way to add a query string to URL in Laravel? Let's say I have a route resources like this

```
Route::get('/test', function() {

});
```

Are there just some parameters I can pass through to make the url look like this
/test?foo=bar

I'm super new to Laravel and I'm really not looking for something fancy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to simply add the query string in to the url exactly as you have suggested `www.example.com/test?foo=bar`. In an example:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    return Input::get("foo");
});
```

This would return `bar`.

Simply use `Input::get()` to retrieve the parameter from the URL.

You can extend this out as much as you want; `www.exmaple.com/test?foo=bar&day=Monday&name=John` and retrieve them all if you needed to using `Input::all()`. Printing this out would return:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [day] => Monday
    [name] => John
)
```

More on the `Input` function here: https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html#method_get

Answer (score 0):

Use  `/test/{foo}` for compulsory and `/test/{foo?}` for optional

```
Route::get('/test/{foo}', function($foo) {
   return "foo value is : ".$foo;
});
```

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Answer (score 0):

You get query string values from the request object:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    $foo = request('foo'); // $foo is now 'bar' or null
});
```